# how can I read values from a mongodb?

Tags: javascript

I'm using meteor as front end for my project and I'm using node.js & mongodb as back end. I have no idea about reading values in meteor. Please help me.

Comment: could you rephrase your question to be a little bit more specific? With what you want to read from a Javascript File? And why?

Comment: Please provide more information, in its current form the question is too vague. The more relevant information you provide, the easier it is for us to help you and the better answers you will get.

Comment: what do you meen by ` values stored in a JavaScript file`

Comment: Also it would be nice to see a piece of code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Pages = new Meteor.Collection("pages");
Meteor.startup(function () {
        if(Pages.find().count() === 0){
            var pages = JSON.parse(MY_JSON_LIST);
            for (page in pages) {
                    Pages.insert(pages[page]);
            }
        }
});
```